# how to call spi driver in window 10 by using c++

Tags: c++, driver, spi

I have a request to write a simple program to call the spi driver in windows 10. I am pretty new to driver stuff. I can't find any spi driver that can be installed in windows, most of the people using linux to get the SPI object. However my case I need to use windows 10 as platform through c++, any sample code would be much appreciate.

Comment: You mean in a Win10 IoT type context.  Like they are doing here? https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/iot/win10/samples/spiaccelerometer

Comment: kind of, but we will be using codeblock to build it, and at the moment we only require to create a wrapper to existing driver

Comment: I've never used that platform that way.  It seems looking at stuff in https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.devices.spi.aspx that MS thinks it should be accessed managed-code style.  There seem to be c++ examples in there, if that helps.  Maybe the Raspberry Pi SE users would have a better handle on it

Comment: the sample look good, however it need to compile in visual studio 2015 with wdk. Any other api/driver that i can use directly to get the spi object?